# Presenting controller and make it root controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

i have a method that present a controller and make presenting controller to be root controller. it worked fine in Xcode 5, but in Xcode 6 it crashes. i need to present view controller and make it root, without any view bugs... old code crashes, new one have bugs while making it root controller

original code

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller withCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    UIViewController *currentController;
    currentController = [self controller];
    [currentController presentViewController:controller animated:true completion:^{
        [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:NULL];
        if(completion){
            completion();
        }
    }];
}
```

tried to change it with delay like

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller withCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    UIViewController *currentController;
    currentController = [self controller];
    [currentController presentViewController:controller animated:true completion:^{
        //use delay before execution
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:NULL];
            if(completion){
                completion();
            }

        });
    }];
}
```

but, i got view flashing with previous view. also tried to make not in a block

```
-(void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)controller withCompletion:(void(^)(void))completion
{
    UIViewController *currentController;
    currentController = [self controller];
    [currentController presentViewController:controller animated:true completion:NULL];
    [controller dismissViewControllerAnimated:false completion:NULL];
    if(completion){
        completion();
    }
}
```

but this way i stuck on previous view.

Comment: Have you tried pushing the view controller?

Comment: On what line it's crashing and what's the error msg?

Comment: if no delay (dispatch_after(...)) it crashes

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to get main navigation controller from a Window object:

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window];
UINavigationController *rootNavController = (UINavigationController *)keyWindow.rootViewController;
```

And set the new root viewcontroller

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[rootNavController setViewControllers:@[rootViewController] animated:NO];
[rootNavController pushViewController:rootViewController animated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"rootViewController shown");
}];
```

Comment: it can be not a UINavigationController, it may by simple UIViewController, so this way is not good. and presenting it modal, not pushing.

Comment: To make a UIViewController as root, you need to set it in your current UINavigationController. When it's done, you can will present your controller.

Comment: read my previous comment: root controller may be not a navigation controller, for example, if i use slide menu, it have inside navigationcontroller, but it still does not make it root controller

    [rootNavController setViewControllers:@[rootViewController] animated:NO];

may cause crash!